# Can't find LUIS app xxxx with authoring key xxxx and region westus

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

When i try to create dispatch model, using Microsoft Bot Framework sdk 4, I am unable to add luis app to the dispatch. I have double checked the id, and authoring keys?

How to troubleshoot such issues !

Comment: Can you provide the steps and commands you used to add it? Sorry, that was a bad link in the now-deleted comment. I [meant to link to this](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch#adding-source-to-dispatch)

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: Yes, it seems, my network firewall is blocking some request to add the luis dispatch model, once i connect with open network it worked.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!